# UICollectionview click event for UISwitch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In the image below the UISwitches below are housed in a collection view. However, I am currently facing a problem where. If I select a switch in the top for example in Roof Structure I select the NON-SABS APPROVED PRODUCT switch when I scroll down another switch for which was not in the view has been selected.

I have followed the following steps to ascertain how man click events are being fired. I used the console to see the output when a switch is selected. 
The results showed that in some instances the switch required switch is only fired as the third event and the other two events that fire are switches that are not in the users view.

To try and solve this issue I tried solve the issue by assigning a negative click event to the switch.
This has so far not worked, see the code below

The code for the **Switch** event

```
public void btnQuestionAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                UITableViewRowSwitch btnQuestionAnswer = (UITableViewRowSwitch)sender;


                    if ((btnQuestionAnswer.section.HasValue) && (btnQuestionAnswer.row.HasValue))
                    {

                        db_QuestionAnswer questionAnswer = questionDataModel[btnQuestionAnswer.section.Value].QuestionAnswers[btnQuestionAnswer.row.Value];

                        //Console.Write(questionAnswer.Answer);
                        Console.WriteLine(questionAnswer.Answer);

                        if ((btnQuestionAnswer.On))
                        {
                            if (questionDataModel[btnQuestionAnswer.section.Value].ComplianceIndicator)
                            {
                                foreach (db_QuestionAnswer QA in questionDataModel[btnQuestionAnswer.section.Value].QuestionAnswers)
                                {
                                    QA.isTicked = false;
                                }
                            }
                            questionAnswer.isTicked = true;
                            // ((UICollectionView)btnQuestionAnswer.relatedView).ReloadData ();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            questionAnswer.isTicked = false;
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        btnQuestionAnswer.On = !btnQuestionAnswer.On;
                    }
                    var element = count.ToString();

            }
```

public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
                {
                    UIView cell;

```
                if (questionDataModel[indexPath.Section].ComplianceIndicator) 
                {
                    cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (QuestionUICollectionViewDelegateDataSource.complianceQuestionCellId, indexPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (QuestionUICollectionViewDelegateDataSource.questionCellId, indexPath);
                }

                int row = indexPath.Row;

                UILabel lblQuestionAnswer = (UILabel)cell.ViewWithTag (1);
                UITableViewRowSwitch btnQuestionAnswer = (UITableViewRowSwitch)cell.ViewWithTag (2);



                btnQuestionAnswer.ValueChanged -= btnQuestionAnswer_Click;

                btnQuestionAnswer.ValueChanged -= btnQuestionAnswer_Click;

                btnQuestionAnswer.ValueChanged += btnQuestionAnswer_Click;
                if (row < questionDataModel [indexPath.Section].QuestionAnswers.Count) 
                {
                    lblQuestionAnswer.Text = questionDataModel[indexPath.Section].QuestionAnswers[indexPath.Row].Answer;

                    btnQuestionAnswer.section = indexPath.Section;
                    btnQuestionAnswer.row = indexPath.Row;


                    btnQuestionAnswer.On = questionDataModel [indexPath.Section].QuestionAnswers [indexPath.Row].isTicked;

                    //----------------TODO----------------//
                    // ---- 
                    btnQuestionAnswer.ValueChanged += btnQuestionAnswer_Click;

                    btnQuestionAnswer.ValueChanged -= btnQuestionAnswer_Click;
                    //if (!btnQuestionAnswer.hasEvent)
                    {
                        btnQuestionAnswer.ValueChanged -= btnQuestionAnswer_Click;
                        //btnQuestionAnswer.ValueChanged -= btnQuestionAnswer_Click;
                        btnQuestionAnswer.ValueChanged += btnQuestionAnswer_Click;

                        //btnQuestionAnswer.hasEvent = true;
                    }

                    btnQuestionAnswer.relatedView = collectionView;
                    if (questionDataModel [indexPath.Section].isLocked) 
                    {
                        btnQuestionAnswer.Enabled = false;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        btnQuestionAnswer.Enabled = true;
                    }

                    lblQuestionAnswer.Hidden = false;
                    btnQuestionAnswer.Hidden = false;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    lblQuestionAnswer.Hidden = true;
                    btnQuestionAnswer.Hidden = true;
                }

                if (controller.loggedInUser.UserType != "Inspector")
                {
                    btnQuestionAnswer.Enabled = false;
                }

                return (UICollectionViewCell)cell;
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely need to override the following methods of the UICollectionViewCell:

```
    public override void PrepareForReuse()
    {
        base.PrepareForReuse();
    }

    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();

    }
```

The problem you're seeing is that the collection view is correctly 'reusing' cell's that have already been loaded into memory, as such it keeps the current 'state' of the controls that are within the cells UIView. So in the prepare for reuse you need to essentially reset all of the UISwitches to their defaults. You could then use the 'AwakeFromNib' override to ensure that the cells that you want to keep the state of their switches are set accordingly. You would probably be wise to have a few bool values within the UIcollectionViewCell that keep hold of the current state of the switches and then apply them in 'AwakeFromNib'. Hope this helps.

Edit:

As it appears you are using static cells at the moment, here is a link to xamarins documentation on deriving your own custom cells from the base UICollectionViewCell. [Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UICollectionViewCell/)

This should give you the information you need to derive the class and give you access to the methods I mentioned above, allowing you a lot more control over what appears and in what state etc.

Comment: How can I add PrepareForReuse i get the following error no suitable error found to modify

Comment: Are you using a custom class for your cells? or are using static cells?

E.g.  public partial class MyDerivedCell : UICollectionViewCell

Comment: class milestoneViewDelegateDataSource : UITableViewSource{} and  class QuestionUICollectionViewDelegateDataSource : UICollectionViewSource {}

Comment: I see, essentially to do what you want, you'd need to derive your own cell class from it's base, that would give you access to the above methods. But that's the only way I am aware of that you can maintain the correct displays when the collection view is de-queuing reusable cells.

Comment: I am a bit lost, i am still finding my footing when working with Xamarin and iOS. would you be able to point me in the right direction on how to solve this.

Comment: no problem George, take a quick look at the link I added to my answer above, read through it and if it doesn't help let me know and I'll try and put together some code for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138847/discussion-between-george-and-digitalsa1nt).